# How do you send HTTP trailers using Plug/Phoenix in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I can't find any information in [plug](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/readme.html) about sending trailers. Is it even possible? With support for HTTP/2 this is important for applications like GRPC

Answer (score 3):

Not right now. Good news is that Plug v1.5 supports Cowboy 2+ which does support trailing headers for both HTTP 1.1 and HTTP 2. So pull requests are definitely appreciated.